# array of wildcard collection initialized with array of rawtype

Tags: java, generics, initialization, wildcard, raw-types

Reasonably enough, compiler would give you Raw type conversion warning for this:

```
//1
List<?> arrList = new ArrayList(); //raw type warning
```

However, compiler is ok (no warning) with this line:

```
//2
List<?>[] arr_of_arrList = new ArrayList[3];// no warning, why ?
```

So, without any complains from compiler I could further do:

```
 arr_of_arrList[0] = new ArrayList<String>();
 arr_of_arrList[1] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Could you please explain why given array initialization (2) is considered type-safe as opposed to first list initialization (1) and what compiler is doing in case 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler will also warn you when defining:

```
List<String>[] foo = new ArrayList[3];
```

This is because by its warning, the compiler trys to make you aware that lists stored in `List<String>[] foo` are possibly not of the generic type `String`. You could always end up with a `List<Integer>` in `foo` at run time:

```
 void main(){

    List<String>[] array = new List[1];
    fill(array);

    // The compiler could not check the array at compile time, so
    // the next line is permitted. But you just created yourself a time bomb.
    List<String> list = array[0];

    // The next line will finally cause a ClassCastException at runtime!
    // Good luck with debugging, especially if you have passed your list
    // arround for a while.
    // If you had defined List<?>[] foo, this assignment would have been
    // forbidden without explicit casting to String. But at least the "type"
    // of the array did not make you false promises about the generic type
    // of the list.
    String value = list.get(0);
 }

 // This method receives an array of lists. At runtime the generic type of
 // the array is gone. Therefore, a call to this method can be called with
 // anz List<SomeType>[] array as an argument. 
 void fill(List<?>[] array) {
   List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   list.add(123)
   array[0] = list;
 }
```

In Java, **arrays of generic types do not have a generic representation**. Instead, all arrays of type `List[]` (in byte code the type is called `[java.util.List`) share one single representation, be it `List<String>` or `List<Integer>` or anyhing else. This is for reasons of backwards compatibility and for how arrays are represented in Java byte code. In other words, the compiler has no way to mark an array **instance** to only accept for example only `List<String>` objects. Instead, the compiler can only mark an array to accept subtypes of `List` as in before Java 5.

By stating

```
List<?>[] foo = new ArrayList[3];
```

you basically tell the compiler that you are aware of the compiler's inability to check for anything more than that all `List`s in the array represented by `foo` are of some subtype of `Object` what is of course trivial. (With `?` being equivalent to `? extends Object`.) Or in other words, when using the wildcard `?`, you ask the compiler to make sure that a `List` contained in `foo` is of **any** generic type. As stated before, because this demand is trivial, the compiler can actually discharge this demand and does not produce a warning.

Now here comes the catch:

```
class MyClass<T extends Number> { }
```

you could still not state:

```
MyClass<? extends Number>[] foo = new MyClass[3];
```

without a compiler warning. Why? I do not know. It should be the *type-safest* declaration. This makes even less sence when seeing that the synonymous declaration

```
MyClass<?>[] foo = new MyClass[3];
```

is accepted. For this reason, I asume that the compiler just skips type checking of generic type variables when arrays are involved entirely but makes sure that you recognized the impossibility of checking generic types of arrays by assuring that the user typed `<?>` compared to legacy code which completely lacks generic types.

Comment: +1 for the efforts. However, case 2 declaration producing no compiler warning is an open question.

Comment: Tryed my best to make my thoughts more clear. What detail are you missing?

Comment: I tried to understand the reason why case 1 is warned and case 2 is considered safe by compiler. Your answer to the second part is " I asume that the compiler just skips type checking of generic type variables when arrays are involved entirely but makes sure that you recognized...", which is good guess, but seem to contradict with the fact that `MyClass<? extends Number>[] foo = new MyClass[3];` is not compiled. Or did I not get it right ?

Comment: You have to understand that an array type of some class `X` is its own type which only relates to class `X` as a constraint for what instances it can contain. I think that what confuses you. Array types cannot be generic for the reasons I describes in the answer. Instead the array type keeps a reference to `X.class` which does not  contain generic types as a result of type erasure. If you tell the compiler that you do not expect the array instances to be of a specific generic type by `?`, the compiler does not need to warn you.

Comment: Since array types are never generic, you do not need to specify a generic type when you construct them. `X[]` means: create some array and check all instances to be a subtype of `X.class` which does not store generic information. The "catch" targets something else. It describes a shortcut the compiler takes when validating array types for type safety compared to non-array generic types. It just checks for the `<?>` instead of actually looking at the class definition. It is an additional detail rather than part of the main answer.

Comment: Perfect, this detailed explanation actually gives the answer : Compiler does not care about `List<?>[]` containing specific instances (because of unbounded wildcard and because it is an array), but it makes sure List<?> arrList is initialized properly.

Answer (score 1):

The `ArrayStoreException` has nothing to do with generics or wildcards at all. `ArrayStoreException` is a fact of life with arrays in Java, even in "type-safe" code:

```
Object[] foo = new Integer[3];
foo[0] = "bar";
```

This is exactly what is happening in your exception. The list returned by `Arrays.asList` is not a `java.util.ArrayList`, hence the `ArrayStoreException`.

Comment: yes, I know the reason of ArrayStoreException, sorry about confusion it brought to the question. My main goal was to understand differences between declarations 1 and 2 from compiler point of view.

Comment: Could you please explain why compiler thinks it is safe to have array of list<?> initialized with array of raw lists, whereas it says its totally unsafe to initialize list<?> with rawtype list.